# React navigation drawer item tint color does not seem original color

Tags: react-native, navigation-drawer, react-navigation

I am using react-native and react-navigation. Drawer Item icon inactive tint colour does not seem to work as I expected. If I apply a tint color, the icon color seems a little bit faded even thought the text seems ok and I if I make it transparent (rgba(0,0,0,0)) it makes it white. I tried several ways but I couldn't find out. If any of you help me I really appreciate.

[Image Is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xMNj.png)

Index.ios.js

```
const CustomDrawerContentComponentDistributor = (props) => (
     <ScrollView><DrawerItems {...props} /></ScrollView>
);

const Distributor = DrawerNavigator({  
  Dashboard: {screen: Dashboard },
  Quality: {screen: Quality},
  },
  {
        drawerPosition: 'left',
        drawerWidth: Dimensions.get('window').width - (Platform.OS === 'android' ? 56 : 64),
    contentOptions: {
        activeTintColor: '#d03036',
        activeBackgroundColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        inactiveBackgroundColor : 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
        inactiveTintColor: '#545f7a',
        style: {
                marginVertical: 0
            },
            labelStyle: {
                fontWeight:'bold',
                fontFamily:'Roboto',
                backgroundColor: 'transparent'
            }
    },

    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponentDistributor
  }
);
```

Page

```
class Quality extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

static navigationOptions = {
    drawerLabel: 'QUALITY',
    drawerIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
        <Image
        source={require('../../img/ic-menu-quality3x.png')}
        style={[styles.menuIcon, { tintColor: "#545f7a", resizeMode:'contain', backgroundColor:'transparent'}]} />
    ),
    header : null
};
```